# Class 'App\TestService' not found - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, service

### Problem

I created service `TestService`, that I use in colntroller file `TestController` in function `test()`.

When I called `test()`, I got an error:

> local.ERROR: Class 'App\TestService' not found {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Class 'App\TestService' not found at /Backend/app/Http/Controllers/TestController.php:8)

### Code

TestController.php:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\TestService;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function test()
    {
        return response()->json(TestService::getTest());
    }
}
```

TestService.php:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use App\TestService;

class TestService
{
    public static function getTest()
    {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

### What I tried

- I checked all the names and they are correct.
- When I wrote in the colntroller file `use App\TestService;`
  I had autocomplete, so the service and name are visible.
- I used these commands to refresh the files: `php artisan serve` and `php artisan clear-compiled`.

But it still doesn't work.

Comment: In which directory are your Test Service?

Comment: In `Backend/app/Services/Tests/TestService.php`

Comment: @Weronika Namespace you have used is not correct.

Comment: So what's the correct one?

Comment: @Weronika `Backend` is root project folder name right?

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya yes, and controller file is in: `Backend/app/Http/Controllers/TestController.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not correctly defined Namespace.
The namespace must be a directory path where you have created a file.

**TestService.php:**

```
<?php
namespace App\Services\Tests;

class TestService
{
    public static function getTest()
    {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

**TestController.php:**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Services\Tests\TestService;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function test()
    {
        //Call service class like.
        return response()->json(TestService::getTest());
    }
}
```

Comment: Code only answers can almost always be improved. What was the problem? What did you change to make it work?

Comment: @brombeer Sure, thanks